# Android Modifying mms.apk

Tags: android, sms, mms

I'll try to explain what I want to do. I have an i9100 SGS2 w/ CM10.1 (so a pretty quick phone).

What I'm trying to do is modify the mms.apk app so that when I hit the send button in an SMS, the messages pops up on the screen right away, and any backend work that needs to be done with sending the message, etc, can be done after it is on the screen.

Right now, if you send a bunch of SMS's one after the other, it seems to lag the OS, and sometimes can take up to a full second between hitting the send button and the actual SMS being shown up in the conversation...it's extremely annoying.

I've decompiled the mms.apk, but don't know what exactly I should be modifying...or if what I need to modify is even in this app?

Any ideas? I know it's a weird request...I'm just trying to get it to feel more like iPhone SMS where there is zero lag whatsoever.

Thanks,
Elliott

Comment: You cannot change compiled code, try different applications from Google Play, maybe one of them will be fast enough

Answer (score 0):

First of all...
This question seems to be more suitable for https://android.stackexchange.com/

As to why this is happening...
Maybe you have a ton of old messages.

Decompiling the APK is not a good idea. Especially when the source code is available for everyone to view, download and modify.

The Mms app source code for CyanogenMod can be found [HERE](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Mms).

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it. I have no idea why this is happening...if you download GO SMS, they have no problems getting it to have no lag at all...